# Does length of wire to NFC antenna affect ability to read tags?

Tags: antenna, rfid, nfc

Most questions regarding NFC antennas pose the question if it's possible in increase the reading area of an antenna.

I'm curious: given a fixed size antenna, does increasing the length of wire between the reader and the antenna affect the ability to read tags?

Comment: I don't think so, if you are using a proper coaxial cable to connect it. But you could also place the NFC module near the antenna, and add longer signal wires going to the Arduino, which might be cheaper.

Comment: This should be separated into two questions I think. One about the antennas should be on Electrical Engineering and the recommendation about NFC modules that support external antennas should be here.

Comment: There is no reference to Arduino in the question. I'll migrate this to Electrical Engineering. Questions about antennas will be better handled there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even coaxial cable will have some attenuation, and although it may not be huge, it still subtracts from the [link power budget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_budget).

Just how much it will subtract depends on the specific type of cable used (there are other things involved, but in this context it comes down to the cable alone), but the short answer is that any added length of connecting cable from the antenna to the actual receiver or transmitter will reduce the effective range of the system when viewed from an antenna to antenna perspective.

Whether the change in effective range is noticeable will depend on the characteristics of the cable, and will go from indiscernible to noticeable (coax varies *widely* in attenuation characteristics depending on the specific one used).